# Python 3: How to check lists within lists with .count()

Tags: list, python-3.x, count, nested

The .count() doesn't check lists within other lists. How can I?

```
FirstList = [ ['1', '2', '3'],
              ['4', '5', '6'],
              ['7', '8', '9'] ]
```

While

```
FirstList[0].count('1')
```

returns 1.
I want to check all of FirstList. How can I do this???

Comment: did my answer solve your problem?

Comment: related: [Flattening a shallow list in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/q/406121/4279)

Comment: Did my answer work for you, @user3573985? If yes, please accept it.

Comment: yeah, you answer solved my problem. I'm new here, what do ya mean 'accept it'?

Comment: click on the checkbox shaped button.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Here are 3 possible solutions:**

given:

```
xs = [['1', '2', '3'],
      ['4', '1', '1'],
      ['7', '8', '1']]

[x.count('1') for x in xs]
```

will return

```
[1, 2, 1]
```

and if you want to reduce that to a single value, use `sum` on that in turn:

```
sum(x.count('1') for x in xs)
```

which will, again, give you:

```
4
```

---

or, alternatively, you can **flatten** the nested list and just run `count('1')` on that once:

```
reduce(lambda a, b: a + b, xs).count('1')
```

which will yield

```
4
```

but as J.F.Sebastian pointed out, this is less efficient/slower than the simple `sum` solution.

or instead of `reduce`, you can use `itertools.chain` for the same effect (without the added computational complexity):

```
list(chain(*xs)).count('1')
```

Comment: -1 for `reduce`, +1 for `x.count('1') for x in xs`. Why would you use `O(n**2)` `reduce` that btw is available only from `functools` in Python 3 if you have `sum(x.count('1') for x in xs)`?

Comment: Yeah, actually the `sum()` one was at the top first but for some reason I felt flattening was simpler; I'll change it back.

Comment: `chain(*xs)` should still be O(n).

Comment: `chain(*xs)` is ok. It could be written as `chain.from_iterable(xs)` (not essential). The point is `reduce` is *less readable* and less efficient. I don't care if a *readable* solution is not the fastest one until a profiler says it is a bottleneck in my application.

Comment: You're right; I started out thinking `flatten` is easy to understand but of course not when it's done via `reduce`.